# custom validation error for two fields unique together django

Tags: django, validation, django-forms, data-cleaning

i want to write my own validation error , for two fields unique together

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    second_field = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    #others
    class Meta:
        unique_together = ('name','second_field')
```

and my forms.py

```
class MyModelForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = MyModel
        fields = '__all__'

    error_messages= {#how to write my own validation error whenever `name and second_field` are unique together }:
```

how to write my own validation error whenever `name and second_field` are unique together?
i need to raise some error if both fields were unique together ?thanks for replying

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From django [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/forms/modelforms/#considerations-regarding-model-s-error-messages) -

> You can override the error messages from NON_FIELD_ERRORS raised by
> model validation by adding the NON_FIELD_ERRORS key to the
> error_messages dictionary of the ModelForm’s inner Meta class

```
from django.core.exceptions import NON_FIELD_ERRORS
from django.forms import ModelForm

class ArticleForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        error_messages = {
            NON_FIELD_ERRORS: {
                'unique_together': "%(model_name)s's %(field_labels)s are not unique.",
            }
        }
```

You can update your `ModelForm` `meta` class as above and create a custom error message.

Comment: thanks , but how to call it in the template? {% if form.NON_FIELD_ERRORS %} {{form.NON_FIELD_ERRORS}} {% endif %}

Comment: I don't think you would need any `if-else` block in your template as this error message will override any error message arising only for `unique_together` constraint.

Comment: we have to write {% for error in form.non_field_errors  %} thanks so much for your help